# How to print a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, printing, cout

I am trying to print a map in an organized way. My map is defined like this:

```
map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;
```

where message is a struct like this:

```
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string msg;
    std::string timestamp;

    message(const std::string& recvbuf_msg,const std::string& a_timestamp) :
    msg(recvbuf_msg), timestamp(a_timestamp), id(++last_id)
  {
  }
};
```

I tried this way of printing it:

```
std::cout << (data[username]).at(0)->msg << std::endl;
```

But it gives a debug error when reaching that function, how can i solve it?

Comment: Well, *which* error does it give?

Comment: R6010 - abort() has been called

Comment: "how can i solve it?" You can use a debugger to find the bug, then you can fix it.

Comment: I used the debugger to find that the error was on that cout.

Comment: then use the debugger to check that `(data[username]).at(0)->msg` is valid before you cout it

Comment: Going deeper in the debugging i found this error: Unhandled exception at at 0x779BDAD8 in Server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0018F684.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `R6010 - abort() has been called` suggests that either there is no entry for key `username` in the map, or the vector of messages for that user is empty. You need to make sure the containers are nonempty before accessing elements. It is a good idea to use iterators, here is an example of how to print the messages for all usernames:

```
for(auto mapIt = data.cbegin(); mapIt != data.cend(); ++mapIt)
{
    std::cout << "printing data for " << mapIt->first << ":" << std::endl;
    for(auto vectIter = mapIt->second.cbegin(); vectIter != mapIt->second.cend(); ++vectIter)
    {
        std::cout << (*vectIter)->msg << ", " << (*vectIter)->timestamp << ", "
                  << (*vectIter)->id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code uses `auto`, so if you are not using a C++11 compliant compiler, you will have to write the iterator types yourself.

Comment: Ok, so to check if the problem is were I write the values in the map I show the code where i write in the map: `std::vector<message *> messages = data.at(*recvbuf_usrn);
 messages.push_back(new message(*recvbuf_msg,currentDateTime()));`                                                         And I know that recvbuf_usrn and recvbuf_msg have the correct contect(I checked when debugging).

Comment: @19mike95 even if you fill it correctly it is safer to check if there really is an element before accessing it.

Comment: @19mike95 That is not the correct way, what you are doing is creating a copy of the vector of messages and adding messages to it. You need to write directly to the vector. Use this: `data.at(*recvbuf_usrn).push_back(new message(*recvbuf_msg,currentDateTime()));`